# Ruby Gem: Uninitialized constant FactoryBot

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

Working on a Ruby gem and trying to use FactoryBot inside with RSpec.

I have this in `support/factory_bot.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  config.before(:suite) do
    FactoryBot.find_definitions
  end
end
```

and in `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'support/factory_bot'
```

When I try to run the spec rake task, I get this error:

```
support/factory_bot.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant FactoryBot (NameError)
```

What am I missing? This used to work fine when I was using the old factory_girl gem, but it has broken with the rename to factory_bot. Thanks!!

Comment: I am not sure that you really need the "config.before(:suite) do" part.

Answer (score 44):

Doh. Silly mistake here, running `bundle exec rake spec` instead of `rake spec` solved it.

Also had to add `require 'factory_bot'` to the top of `support/factory_bot.rb`

Answer (score 29):

Overview just in case you are doing this from scratch

installation `rspec` details [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) (basically add `gem` to `Gemfile` then run `bundle install`)

initialize `RSPEC` in your rails project `rails g rspec:install`

create new file your `spec/support/factory_bot.rb` add the following base code:

```
require 'factory_bot'

RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end

# RSpec without Rails
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

    config.before(:suite) do
        FactoryBot.find_definitions
    end
end
```

add reference on `spec/rails_helper.rb`

```
require 'support/factory_bot'
```

as well as remove any `fixture` unused reference like this one
    `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`

That should be it!, finally run any `spec` file you want inside rspec default folders
e.g.:
`spec/features/my_action_spec.rb`

`spec/models/my_model_spec.rb`

`spec/task/my_task_spec.rb`

or run them all and check depending on your setup

`rspec`

`rails rspec`

`bundle exec rspec`

hope this helps someone with the whole `RSPEC` + `FactoryBot` `Gem` installation process

Comment: All I had to do was require 'factory_bot' in rails_helper.rb

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too, remove the

```
require 'support/factory_bot'
```

There's a line on rails_helper, just uncomment it:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].sort.each { |f| require f }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered and issue similar to this. I worked around it by removing the default testing suite ( MiniTest ). When you create a rails application and intend on using rspec and factory_bot, use the code below in the command line:

`rails new myapp -T`

Hope this helps xP

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to put those lines below '`require "rspec/rails"` in file:
`spec/rails_helper.rb`:

like:

```
require "rspec/rails"
require_relative "support/factory_bot"
require_relative "support/chrome"
```